# Struts 2 Conditional Annotation Validation without XML

Tags: java, validation, struts2, annotations

I have a form with several fields (i.e. a,b,c,d,...) and the project I am currently doing right now is using Annotations for form validation in Struts2. XML usage is being discouraged.

I need to check a certain condition before I will validate form elements b, c, and d.

I was able to do the following:

```
@Validations {  
 requiredStrings = {
   @RequiredStringValidator(...),
   @RequiredStringValidator(...),
  }
}
public String doSomething(){
  ...
 return SUCCESS;
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Struts2 Annotation alone? Most similar questions I have found in SO all tell me to use XML method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an expression validator, or write a custom validator.